# NSMenu Pressed Mouse Button in 10.5

Tags: cocoa, macos, osx-leopard, nsevent

I’m updating (downdating?) an application I’ve written for 10.6+ to work in 10.5+. I’m struggling with capturing the currently pressed mouse button in the `-(void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *);` selector.

For 10.6+ I’m taking advantage of the [`[NSEvent pressedMouseButtons]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/EventObjectsTypes/EventObjectsTypes.html) which allows me to get the pressed button outside the event stream. However, this doesn’t exist in 10.5+ (it appears I need to call `[theEvent buttonNumber]`.

How do I capture the pressed mouse button (right or left):

1. Inside of my NSMenu delegate
2. Preferably inside the `-(void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu` selector
3. In a manor that works in both 10.5+ and 10.6+

I really appreciate the help and know StackOverflow will help a new Objective-C programmer out!

Thanks,
Dustin

Comment: That is the best way to do it, but you can just use [[NSApp currentEvent] buttonNumber]. NSApp is a global variable which points to the application object.

Comment: Dustin Senos: You should post that as an answer on your own question. I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end I was able get the current mouse button by calling (thanks to [Nick Paulson](http://nickpaulson.com/) for the help):

`[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent] buttonNumber]`

As [ughoavgfhw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/458390/ughoavgfhw) pointed out a shorter way of fetching the same event is though:

`[[NSApp currentEvent] buttonNumber]`

Comment: Wanted to add to this answer for those who are adding support for older machines. Make sure you’re not just checking for the right mouse button (which may or may not exist on an older machine) but checking to see if the user is holding the control key when clicking (often used on older machines to toggle a context menu): `if ([[NSApp currentEvent] modifierFlags] & NSControlKeyMask) { … do code }`

Answer (score 2):

Another way would be to create a CGEventTap that captures mouse down events.
You then just have to remember the last event type and check that in one of your NSMenu delegate methods.
Here is some sample code:

```
CGEventRef MouseClickedEventCallback(CGEventTapProxy proxy, CGEventType type, CGEventRef event, void* refcon)
{
    CGPoint location = CGEventGetLocation(event);   
    switch (type) 
    {
        case kCGEventLeftMouseDown:
        {
            NSLog(@"Left Mouse pressed at %@", NSStringFromPoint(NSPointFromCGPoint(location)));
            break;
        }           
        case kCGEventRightMouseDown:
        {
            NSLog(@"Right Mouse pressed at %@", NSStringFromPoint(NSPointFromCGPoint(location)));
            break;
        }   
        case kCGEventOtherMouseDown:
        {
            NSLog(@"Other Mouse pressed at %@", NSStringFromPoint(NSPointFromCGPoint(location)));
            break;          
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return event;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    CGEventMask eventMask = CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventLeftMouseDown)|CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventRightMouseDown)|CGEventMaskBit(kCGEventOtherMouseDown);
    CFMachPortRef eventTap = CGEventTapCreate(kCGSessionEventTap, kCGHeadInsertEventTap, 0, eventMask, MouseClickedEventCallback, NULL);
    CFRunLoopSourceRef runLoopSource = CFMachPortCreateRunLoopSource(kCFAllocatorDefault, eventTap, 0);
    CFRunLoopAddSource(CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), runLoopSource, kCFRunLoopCommonModes);
    CGEventTapEnable(eventTap, true);
}
```

The [Quartz Event Services docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/Reference/reference.html) state that:

> Event taps receive key up and key down
>   events if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> - The current process is running as the
>     root user.
> - Access for assistive
>     devices is enabled. In Mac OS X v10.4,
>     you can enable this feature using
>     System Preferences, Universal Access
>     panel, Keyboard view.

I double checked that and it seems that you really don't have to enable assistive devices to receive mouse events.

But if `[[[NSApplication sharedApplication] currentEvent] buttonNumber]` does what you want, I'd definitely go with that. It's higher level and therefore less code.

Comment: Really appreciate the help/code weichsel, it’s always good to see different approaches to the same problem. As you stated, the `[NSApplication sharedApplication]` approach is doing what I want, and is higher level, so I’ll go with it for now.

Comment: This helped hugely. Thanks!